# Are some detached DOM elements acceptable/unavoidable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory, developer-tools

I'm building a React website and started getting an error message that there is a memory leak. Long story short, I figured out the source of the leak and resolved it, or at least got the error message to disappear.

But when I take HEAP snapshots, there still appears to be a memory leak. I'm still getting several DetachedHTMLDivElements and a bunch of other detached items that I'm not sure are relevant. I've attached the snapshot below.

[image: HEAP snapshot]

As someone new to web development, is it ever OK to have detached DOM elements? Are there situations where it's just unavoidable? Or should we always be eliminating these from our code?

Comment: The alternative to having detached elements being to have them attached? It's better they're detached. If there is no JS reference to it, then the GarbageCollector will pick them when required. However beware since these are DOM objects, the GC may not be the one used to collect JS objects, so IIRC hitting the "collect garbage" button may not work. That doesn't mean the browser will be unable to collect them.

Comment: What I meant is: are detached elements always indicative of a problem in your code? So, the alternative would be they are attached or removed by the garbage collector.  When I was researching memory leaks, it seemed like having detached elements hanging around is inherently bad. Since I resolved the memory leak error message in my code but still have detached elements, I wasn't sure what to make of them.

Comment: Not necessarily, as long as your code doesn't hold references to these nodes you're fine and should let the browser deal with it.